# Transfer data from Raspberry Pi to Online Server

Tags: php, sql, raspberry-pi

I'm relatively new to using Raspberry Pi's and Web Servers, but I'm working on a project where I want to read an ID number off a RFID card using a scanner and transfer that ID number to an online web server that contains a SQL database using a Raspberry Pi.

What is the best way to transfer the ID number from the Raspberry Pi to the online server?

I've looked online and most articles talk about creating a web server on the Pi, but is that necessary? Is there any way just to send a string or CSV file straight from the Pi to the SQL database on the online server? If so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two ways to achieve it:

1. Connect directly to database server using whatever language you want to (eg. php, bash) and then insert ID to your table.
2. Create WebService on your remote server and send ID from Raspberry Pi to that WebService. Then WS will connect to database and insert it.

Second way is better because you've more control over it (eg. you can validate that ID or change database structure without changing Raspberry Pi application).
In both cases you don't need web server on Raspberry Pi side.

Comment: I think REST will be enough for that task. You can easily build such server with few lines of PHP.